# How can I format a positive/negative number with th:class?

Tags: css, thymeleaf

If I have a `BigDecimal`, is it possible to easily format it with a CSS class based on whether it's positive or negative?

Like:

`th:class="${#numbers.isPositive(myBigDecimal) ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success'}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the best workaround is:

`th:class="${myBigDecimal != null && myBigDecimal > 0 ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success'}"`